# Can it be more clean or/and less line with the same functionality?

Tags: python

**Can it be more clean or less lines of code?
I feel like  it can be more simple with the same functionality, what your opinion?
Does it look clean enough to you, would you do something a different way?**

```py
for i in range(workers):
    Years = input("Years of job: ")
    while Years == "":
        Years = input("Dont leave blank, enter years: ")
    Years = int(Years)
    while Years < 0:
        Years = input("Please enter positive number: ")
        Years = int(Years)
    Sallary = input("Sallary: ")
    Sallary = int(Sallary)
    if Years >= 5:
        for j in range(5):
            degree = input("Give vathmos: ")
            while degree not in "ABC" or degree == "":
                degree = input("Please enter A, B or C: ")
            if degree == "A":
                sum1 += 1
            elif degree == "B":
                sum2 += 1
            elif degree == "C":
                sum3 += 1
        if (sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):
            Sallary = Sallary + ((10 / 100) * Sallary)
        elif (sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):
            Sallary = Sallary + ((15 / 100) * Sallary)
        print("A=", sum1, "B=", sum2, "C=", sum3)
        print("sallary is: ", Sallary, "Working years are: ", Years)
    else:
        for j in range(Years):
            degree = input("Give vathmos: ")
            while degree not in "ABC" or degree == "":
                degree = input("Please enter A, B or C: ")
            if degree == "A":
                sum1 += 1
            elif degree == "B":
                sum2 += 1
            elif degree == "C":
                sum3 += 1
        if (sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):
            Sallary = Sallary + ((10 / 100) * Sallary)
        elif (sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):
            Sallary = Sallary + ((15 / 100) * Sallary)
        print("A=", sum1, "B=", sum2, "C=", sum3)
        print("sallary is: ", Sallary, "Working years are: ", Years)
```

Comment: Dare to describe the code at least?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stack overflow! Try to keep your questiong focused!

Comment: This question is probably more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @user14512961 you need comments in all your codes to make them clearer. Apparently there are some madlads who think code should be self-describing but I believe exactly the opposite: write the algorithm as comments, then fill in the "paragraphs" with the implementation itself.

Comment: sorry guys ill for sure do it in my next post :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be like this. First of all, as @lime noticed the condition `elif (sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):` is completely useless (unless you meant something else).

Now for the code, the biggest shrinkage can be done by removing duplicated  branches of big `if` statement. The branches only differ in one value - the loop limit, so you can find the limit in advance, save in in a variable, and then make your loop up to this limit.

Next, you can count degrees with a simple `dict` object. Finally, there are a few improvement in how you input and print the data.

```
for i in range(workers):
    Years = 0
    while Years <= 0:
        try: Years = int(input("Years of job: "))
        except: pass
    
    Sallary = int(input("Sallary: "))
    
    Degrees = { degree:0 for degree in "ABC" }
    nInputDegrees = min(Years, 5)
    for j in range(nInputDegrees):
        degree = input("Give vathmos: ")
        while degree not in "ABC" or degree == "":
            degree = input("Please enter A, B or C: ")
        Degrees[degree] += 1

    if Degrees["A"] >= 3 and Degrees["B"] == 0:
        Sallary *= 1.1
    else:
        Sallary *= 1.15
        
    for degree, count in Degrees:
        print(f"{degree}={count}", end=' ')
    print()
    print(f"Sallary is: {Sallary}, Working years are: {Years}")
```

Comment: @user14512961 This is a great answer. Make sure you take a look at this one too. +1

Comment: wow thats a very nice code i dint know this tricks yet thanks tho :)

Comment: Im getting this error when i run it " for degree, count in Degrees:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)" i putted 5 A's at the degree question

Comment: @user14512961, yeah it should be `for degree, count in Degrees.items()`, I forgot that by default it would iterate only over keys, not both keys and values

Answer (score 1):

Here is one thing to consider:

```
if (sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):
  Sallary = Sallary + ((10 / 100) * Sallary)
elif (sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):
  Sallary = Sallary + ((15 / 100) * Sallary)
```

The `elif` seems to be completely useless. They both check for `(sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0)`.

The code can become more concise if you remove the `elif`.

Additionally, the code within `if Years >= 5` and the coorisponding `else` looks very similar except for the number of iterations in the for loop. Because we have dulicate code, we can consider using a function for this process.

Consider the following as well:

```
if Years >= 5:
  SallaryCalculator(5)
else:
  SallaryCalculator(Years)
```

Below is what will be in `SallaryCalculator()`:

```
def SallaryCalculator(Years):
  global sum1, sum2, sum3, Sallary, Year
  for j in range(Years):
    degree = input("Give vathmos: ")
  while degree not in "ABC" or degree == "":
    degree = input("Please enter A, B or C: ")
  if degree == "A":
    sum1 += 1
  elif degree == "B":
    sum2 += 1
  elif degree == "C":
    sum3 += 1
  if (sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):
    Sallary = Sallary + ((10 / 100) * Sallary)
  elif(sum1 >= 3) & (sum2 == 0):
    Sallary = Sallary + ((15 / 100) * Sallary)
  print("A=", sum1, "B=", sum2, "C=", sum3)
  print("sallary is: ", Sallary, "Working years are: ", Years)
  return
```

Comment: yes i just saw and edited that elif i ment to write something else but i forgot because i copy paste it.. also how would the SallaryCalucator work is it the def ?

Comment: @user14512961 There try that. Is this your first time using functions or were you just having trouble understanding how to implement it into a function?

Comment: i had to put sum1,sum2,sum3 into the def and also im getting "Shadow name "Year" from outer scope" and "Shadow name "Sallary" from outer scope" it work fine tho

Comment: @user14512961 Oh my. Huge oversight on my end. Meant to make those variables `global` in the function. Give that a shot. With`global` you shouldn't have to pass in any more variables other than `Years`. Unfortunately where I'm working right now I cannot test this code.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously consider what others have said about asking good questions on StackOverflow, as well as clarity about what your code is supposed to be doing (e.g., the redundant elif). But, here is a working version of what I *think* you were going for.

```
from collections import defaultdict

workers = ('Demba Allende', 'Molly Oriji', 'Taegu Naoduelle')

for worker in workers:
    years = 0
    while not years:
        year_text = input(f"\nHow many years has {worker} had on the job? ").strip()
        try:
            years = int(year_text)
        except ValueError:
            print(f'"{year_text}" is not a valid number of years on the job, try again.')
            years = 0
    salary = 0
    while not salary:
        salary_text = input(f"\nWhat is {worker}'s current salary? ").strip().replace(',', '')
        try:
            salary = float(salary_text)
        except ValueError:
            print(f'"{salary_text}" is not a valid salary, try again.')
            salary = 0

    # I don't know what vathmos ratings are, but ok...
    degree_sum = defaultdict(int)
    valid_degrees = ('A', 'B', 'C')
    iterations = years if years < 5 else 5
    for year in range(iterations):
        degree = ""
        while degree not in valid_degrees:
            degree = input(f"Give vathmos for {worker} in year #{year + 1} (A, B, or C): ").strip().upper()
            try:
                assert degree in valid_degrees
                degree_sum[degree] += 1
            except AssertionError:
                print(f'"{degree}" is not a valid vathmos, it must be either A, B, or C. Try again.')
                degree = ""

    # your if and elif used identical conditions, so I'm not sure what you want.
    # I just guessed...
    if degree_sum['A'] >= 3 and degree_sum['B'] == 0:
        # you got 3 or more A ratings and no B ratings, give the biggest salary boost
        salary += 10 / 100 * salary
    elif degree_sum['A'] < 3 and degree_sum['B'] > 0:
        # you got fewer than 3 A ratings, but at least 1 B rating, give smaller salary boost
        salary += 10 / 100 * salary
    print(f"\n-------------\nWorker: {worker}")
    print(f"Vathmos ratings: {dict(sorted(degree_sum.items()))}")
    print(f"Salary is: {salary:0.2f}")
    print(f"Working years are: {years}\n")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer also from what i have noticed, most of you use dict ill have to look at that more. Also vathmos means :'Grade' in greeklish i just forgot to change it...